# Escape variable in Jenkins shell execution

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

We use Jenkins to run some Wordpress CLI stuff for us, and I would like to pass in some PHP to the Wordpress CLI.  For example:

```
cd wordpress && wp core config --skip-check --dbhost=dbhost --dbname=dbname --dbuser=user --dbpass=pass --extra-php <<PHP
define('HOST', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
PHP
```

Jenkins interprets the `$_SERVER` and I'm left with `['HTTP_HOST']`.  How can I escape `$_SERVER`?

I've tried doing `define('HOST', \$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);`, but that still gets interpreted as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out...   Wrap the first section of defining HEREDOC in double quotes.

```
cd wordpress && wp core config --skip-check --dbhost=dbhost --dbname=dbname --dbuser=user --dbpass=pass --extra-php <<"PHP"
define('HOST', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
PHP
```

It no longer interprets `$_SERVER`.

Comment: Yes. --extra-php <<"PHP" fixed it.